# How to select last child of a given element type when there are other elements after it?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I've got basically this:

```css
.table .row .cell {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table .row .cell:first-child span {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.table .row .cell:last-child span {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.table .row .details {
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 80%;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"><span>first cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>second cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>third cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell right"><span>fourth cell</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"><span>first cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>second cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>third cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell right"><span>fourth cell<span></div>
    <div class="details">details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"><span>first cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>second cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>third cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell right"><span>fourth cell<span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm wanting to have the last .cell in the second row to have a padding on the right but can't figure this one out. Hopefully it's an easy fix and I won't have to rewrite everything.

Comment: dynamic or static configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.table .row .cell {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table .row .cell:first-child span {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.table .row .cell:last-child span {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.table .row .details {
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 80%;
}

.right {

  text-align: right;
}

.table .row:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(4) span {
  padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"><span>first cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>second cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>third cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell right"><span>fourth cell</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"><span>first cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>second cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>third cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell right"><span>fourth cell<span></div>
    <div class="details">details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"><span>first cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>second cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>third cell<span></div>
    <div class="cell right"><span>fourth cell<span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah k yeah I suppose I could do that. This table is generated dynamically so the number of columns can change based on the context.

I ended up adding a check if it's the last column, and in that case add in the according style:
`table__header ${index === (columns.length - 1) ? 'pad-right' : ''}`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user161592 why accepting this answer if you ended up using another one and not this one?